# Can Google Analytics access PHP session data?

Tags: php, session, google-analytics, analytics

On my website I track my users with a PHP session variable user ID called $uID. Is there any way I can give Google Analytics access to $uID so I can track website usage based on this instead of just IP?

I'm interested in how individual users are using my site and this would be superior to writing my own tracking scripts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As with any other JavaScript, there is no way for it to get direct access to the server side session store.

You can output that information to the HTML document when the page is generated by the server. You can store it in JavaScript (via a `<script>` element) or embed it somewhere in the HTML (such as a `<meta>` element or a `data-*` attribute on an appropriate element).

```
<meta name="uID" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['uID']); ?>">

var myuID = document.querySelector('meta[name="uID"]').getAttribute('content');
```

Answer (score 0):

Google has [an example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-id) of how to do this with `analytics.js`.
In your case, it would be something like:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

// New Google Analytics code to set User ID.

<?php
// New Google Analytics code to set User ID.
// $userId is a unique, persistent, and non-personally identifiable string ID.
if (is_array($_SESSION) && isset($_SESSION['UserID'])) {
  $gacode = "ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', { 'userId': '%s' });";
  echo sprintf($gacode, $_SESSION['UserID']);
}?>

ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

If you are using the older `ga.js`, you can use [Custom Variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables), but the implementation is more dependant on exactly what you want to track.